# Einstein's Photoelectric Equation and analyzing its graph

Tags: photoelectric-effect

According to the equation, the graph of kinetic energy of emitted photoelectrons from a metal vs the frequency of incident radiation gives a straight line.

[image]

Source: [By Klaus-Dieter Keller [CC BY 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0)], via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3APhotoelectric_effect_diagram.svg)

My doubt is, what factors does the slope of this line depend on? I think it depends on the nature of metal used. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Welp, I fear you are wrong. The slope is supposedly a fundamental constant of nature!

Comment: Okay, but does depend on the intensity of incident radiation as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point at which the line starts does depend on the metal used, (it's work function) but the energy of the emitted electrons is independent of the intensity, and dependent only on the energy (i.e. frequency) of the individual photons.

[Photoelectric Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) on Wikipedia gives a full account.

[image]

Source: [Hyperphysics Work Function](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html)

Element          Work Function(eV)

Aluminum 4.08

Beryllium 5.0

Cadmium 4.07

Calcium 2.9

Carbon 4.81

Cesium 2.1

Cobalt 5.0

Copper 4.7

Gold 5.1

Iron 4.5

Lead 4.14

Magnesium 3.68

Mercury 4.5

Nickel 5.01

Niobium 4.3

Potassium 2.3

Platinum 6.35

Selenium 5.11

Sodium 2.28

Uranium 3.6

Zinc 4.3